# batch Remove colon from directory/file path

Tags: windows, batch-file

How to remove ':' from file/directory path `d:\apps`

Looking for output: `d\apps`

Cant get away with string substitution. Any help!

Comment: Why can't you use string substitution?

Comment: Apologies for being dump.. got this working as soon as I posted this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "var=d:\apps"
SET "var2=%var::=%"
SET var

GOTO :EOF
```

Works perfectly happily for me - what's your actual problem?

Comment: >what's your actual problem? | For me it was Batch's syntax. I knew what to do but it didn't work until I copied your answer 1 for 1 and replaced the bits that I needed. Thanks

Comment: @Hobbamok Hold up, wait a minute—Batch has a syntax? I don't think those words belong so close to each other in the same sentence.

Comment: @MajorMalfunction I typed in the commands and arguments but what I wanted did not happen => problem with the syntax. It has very little and even worse: it's not telling you what you did wrong, but it has enough syntax to mess up